# Python yfinance startdate enddate not match

Tags: python-3.x, yfinance

I am trying to get the exact one-day stock data from yfinance, but I found the date may take a day before the startdate and enddate in the requests.

The code I have used:

```
result = yf.download(tickers = 'aapl', start = '2022-03-10',end = '2022-03-10', prepost = True,  progress=False)
```

The above will return the data on 2022-03-09. But what I want is the data on the 2022-03-10.

Comment: What if you enter `start = '2022-03-10',end = '2022-03-11'`?

Comment: It return the result for both 2022-03-09 and 2022-03-10, so strange.

Comment: Is it crucial to use `yfinance`? In my opinion, [`pandas-datareader`](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#documentation) is a better choice. Maybe it wouldn't be a bad idea to check it out.

Comment: I can use another sources. But tried to run the similar request to yaoo, it wil return more data. ```result = web.DataReader('AAPL', 'yahoo',start = '2022-03-10',end = '2022-03-11')``` will give the date from 2022-03-09 to  2022-03-11.

Comment: It's not a big deal. Just grab the row that you need.

Answer (score 1):

In that case, you can retrieve the data for two days and just remove one row.

```
result = yf.download(tickers = 'aapl', start = '2022-03-10',end = '2022-03-11', prepost = True,  progress=False)

result.drop(index="2022-03-09", inplace=True)

print(result)

                  Open        High  ...   Adj Close     Volume
Date                                ...                       
2022-03-10  160.199997  160.389999  ...  158.520004  105342000

[1 rows x 6 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use -1 offset:

```
end = (pd.to_datetime("2022-03-10") - pd.DateOffset(days=-1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```